# How do we start reading the vedas and puranas along with our kids?

Tags: scripture, vedas, children, parents

What are few guide lines for start studying scripture along with our Kids?
Vedas/Puranas are to be learnt under the guidance of a guru.
They are not bed-time stories to read with children.
So what is the exact guidelines in terms of Age, and order of scripture etc?

Comment: A lot of puranas are lovingly passed down as bed time stories from grandparent to grandchild. In fact, these have a much more lasting impact on the child, than listening to formal upanyasa/pravachana

Answer (score 1):

1. A first thing is a plan to prepare, what you want to read about.
2. Best idea is to start with 2 main books

> 1. Bhrama Puran
> 2. Bhramanda Puran

These 2 puranas have details about how shrishti started and about yugas etc. You can start with these.